# How to enforce Basic Authentication when fetching WSDL (Server side)

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, wsdl, server-side

I'm looking for a way to force the client side to use HTTP Basic Authentication when it attempts to retrieve my `WSDL` file.
Using `JAX-WS` I created the following web service, I use GlassFish 3:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Hello")
@Stateless
public class HelloService {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "sayHello")
    @RolesAllowed("myrole")
    public String sayHello(@WebParam(name = "name") @XmlElement(required=true) String name){
        return "Hello "+name;
    }
}
```

After googling around, it seems that adding a security constraint to the `web.xml` descriptor should take care of this, so I did

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>HelloSC</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HelloRC</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>myrole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Now, when I deploy and point my browser to http://`myserver`/Hello, The browser asks for credentials. Also the `sayHello` method can only be consumed with the right credentials.

QUESTION:
So far so good but if I point the browser to the WSDL (http://`myserver`/Hello/HelloService?wsdl) I'm not asked for credentials, it just loads, and it's a requirement that it should be password protected

It's my understanding that the url-pattern should apply for the WSDL as well. it is a GET request after all...

Any pointers?

Edit: So I deployed the .war to a JBoss Instance and it works as intended. Seems there is some config missing for GlassFish.

Comment: Why would you protect the WSDL?

Comment: Right now it's mainly a requirement for security auditing, but I can see the value in preventing someone from just look at your WS definition (see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-723)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, this only worked after adding the security-constraint in the GlassFish 3 specific descriptor:
**META-INF/glassfish-ejb-jar.xml**:

```
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
      <ejb-name>HelloService</ejb-name>
      <webservice-endpoint>
        <port-component-name>Hello</port-component-name>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </webservice-endpoint>
    </ejb>
  </enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

and then remove the security constraint from **web.xml**

Answer (score 0):

You configurations look correct. I suppose if you open `http://example.org/Hello/HelloService?wsdl` in a new browser (or close all windows of your current browser in open it again) you will be required to perform the Basic authentication.
The issue here that after the first successful authentication a browser sends the Basic Authentication header in each request and the request is authenticated by a server.

*Added after the comment*
Please try to add additional http-method

```
<http-method>DELETE</http-method>
<http-method>PUT</http-method>
<http-method>HEAD</http-method>
<http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
<http-method>TRACE</http-method>
<http-method>GET</http-method>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
```

Comment: That was my first thought, But I've tried clearing the cache and even from another server with wget without being asked for credentials

Comment: Did you try a close your browser at all and first access to wsdl when you open it again?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I added the http headers and tried closing everything, but it's still the same

Comment: Ok, my last try to help: remove all http-method elemtns from the web.xml.